# Camera preview layer makes button invisible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, storyboard

I'm trying to add a button over a camera preview but it doesn't show up when I run the program (I have constraints). I looked into the code and tried to debug but I'm new to swift and Xcode and I'm new to debugging in general. I saw that when I commented out the camera preview layer the button showed up. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import QuartzCore

class View1: UIViewController , AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer:CALayer!
var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView:UIView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    prepareCamera()
}

func prepareCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

    if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],                                                                                                          mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,                                                                                                             position: .back).devices {

        captureDevice = availableDevices.first
        beginSession()
    }
}

func beginSession() {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        //Figure out what to do here 
 }
    if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {



        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput){

            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        }

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.PhotoAllergy.captureQueue")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try setting the `zPosition` of the button to 1 or higher. `YourButtonName.layer.zPostion = 2`

[Apple Documentation on ZPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition)

Comment: I tried to set it to 999 before and it didn't help :(

Comment: Im confused. When I set it to 1 it works but it doesn't work at 999 when I did it before. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem! Do you also get when a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when you try to resize a UIButton?

Comment: I figured out what that problem was it was my bad but if I change the button to either have a background or if I change it to a image it just doesn't show up. I tried with a image viewer now too and it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
You just have to add button as subview to view that is working as a preview for your avcamera.

class RecordVC {
    @IBOutlet weak var vwRecordVideo : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnGallary : UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        vwRecordVideo.addSubview(cameraButton)
        vwRecordVideo.addSubview(btnGallary)
     }
}
```